# How to get max(column value) based on another column value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with following schema and sample values.

[image]

I am trying to write a query which will give me for each user its max(timestamp) for connected status as well as disconnected status.

Example of the output schema for the required query I am looking for is:

**Username | Connected_MAX_Timestamp | Disconnected_MAX_Timestamp**

The query which I tried is this :

**SELECT username,socketstatus,max(timestamp) from socketinfo group by username,socketstatus**

and the output for the same is :

[image]

Can someone tell me how to achieve the required output ?

Comment: For future reference, this is a pivot table.  It's a somewhat unusual one, pivoting on only two values of the variable (Connected / Disconnected), but that's the operation you're trying to perform.

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select username,
       max(case when socketstatus = 'Connected' then timestamp end) as max_connected_timestamp,
       max(case when socketstatus = 'Disconnected' then timestamp end) as max_disconnected_timestamp,
from socketinfo
group by username;
```

Comment: Thanks,It works.                                                                                     
 Further in this code, can we do something to retain max(max_conn,max_disconn) ?

Comment: @AmrataRamchandani . . . I don't understand your comment, unless you want `max(case when socketstatus in ('Connected', 'Disconnected') then timestamp end)`.

Comment: No, What I meant was finding max_of_connected & max_disconnected and compare between this two MAX's to find the greatest of two

Comment: @AmrataRamchandani . . . Ask another question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation.

Comment: I found some way to get that, I am doing the comparision after fetching the results. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.username,
       t1.socketstatus,
       max(t1.timestamp) AS "Connected_MAX_Timestamp",
       t2.username,
       t2.socketstatus,
       max(t2.timestamp) "Disconnected_MAX_Timestamp"
FROM socketinfo t1,
     socketinfo t2
WHERE t1.socketstatus='Connected'
  AND t2.socketstatus='Disconnected'
  AND t1.username=t2.username
GROUP BY t1.username,
         t1.socketstatus,
         t2.username,
         t2.socketstatus;
```

This works on Postgres 9.5, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Further in this code, can we do somthing to retain only max(conn_TS,disconn_TS) ?

Comment: I mean max(max_conn_TS,max_disconn_TS) ? that was the ultimate goal actually

Comment: Use Gordon's query, it's more concise. Then add before the "from" clause: 
   ... max(timestamp) as max_overall_timestamp ...

If you need to know whether this was a connected or disconnected moment, add:
       case when max(timestamp) = max(case when socketstatus = 'Connected' then timestamp end) then 'overall max when connected' else 'overall max when disconnected' END ...